# How to remove an object form the List but not from Realm

Tags: android, realm

I'm getting the 
**Removing is not supported.**
while trying to remove an item from the list:

```
List<Animal> animals = realm.allObjects(Animal.class);
animalsForFragment = createAnimals(animals);

private Map<Integer, Animal> createAnimals(List<Animal> animals) {
        Map<Integer, Animal> animalMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Animal animal: animals){
            if (animal.getUniqueId() == animalId) {
                animals.remove(animal);
                animalMap.put(1, animal);
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

I suppose it happens because Realm thinks that I want him to delete this record but I just want to work with current snapshot of this list. How can I do that?

Comment: Does anything keep you from copying the List to f.e. LinkedList and then operate on it instead of the RealmResults?

Comment: You can use `realm.copyFromRealm()` to get a in-memory snapshot that is not connected to Realm. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You can make an answer and I'll mark it as correct one.